# Limit layout to only hdpi density

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that I want to show ONLY on hdpi screens. Using the density qualifier `hdpi` does nothing and I still see the layout on larger devices. Is the qualifier not working or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

From the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) we see that:

> Note: Using a density qualifier doesn't imply that the resources are only for screens of that density. If you don't provide alternative resources with qualifiers that better match the current device configuration, the system may use whichever resources are the best match.

Basically, the system tries to find a better resource, but the one designed for `hdpi` is the best. If you want to use that only on `hdpi`, then you should probably create alternative resources for `mdpi` and `xhdpi` to be used for the rest of the screens.